# UITableView overlaps status bar on iOS7 beta 4

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Here is a UITableView that worked fine in iOS6 overlapping the status bar in iOS7. What is the best way to solve this problem? Using iOS7 beta 4. This behavior existed since beta 1.

META:
Complain about me disobeying NDA to Apple directly at 800-275-2273 or Stack Overflow at 212-232-8294; or help me solve this problem here which is clearly superior to Apple's forums.

[image]

Comment: There are videos that discuss this subject in this year's WWDC collection, I suggest you take a look at them.

Comment: Could you please let me know which video addresses this issue?

Comment: @FullDecent : The thing is iOS 7 is not released & no one have idea what is wrong as most of us don't have iOS 7 as of now... I don't think you will get proper reply to this question...

Comment: @Downvoters : I don't think we should downvote for the reason **under NDA**

Comment: It's not Stack Overflow's job to police Apple's (or indeed anyone else's) NDAs. If you have a problem with people posting questions like this contact Apple who can then contact SE directly.

Comment: Upvote question if you are less than satisfied with Apple developer forums and its search feature. But please let me know if you can recommend which Apple dev video addresses this specific issue I am sure everyone is having.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're happy to have the "Language" section title to not overlap but don't mind the content overlapping once you scroll past it you can try this in your ViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 
                                       self.tableView.contentInset.left, 
                                       self.tableView.contentInset.bottom, 
                                       self.tableView.contentInset.right)];
```

Comment: Looks like I will do this conditionally if running iOS7.

Answer (score 2):

One answer is described here https://devforums.apple.com/message/830042#830042 (yes, you need to be a paid developer to access it). All answers are various levels of hackery. Given how bad this situation is, there will probably be a different solution in the final version.

As per the rant thread (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/197429?tstart=0 "We all are royally screwed!!!") I do really think Apple should be using its own resources for beta testing rather than leaning on its vendors. In a FOSS project we would call this a community, but Apple is closed so we are vendors.

Comment: Based on this, updating question to specify beta version

Comment: Looks like beta 6 is fixing this issue

Answer (score 2):

Starting with iOS 7, this is the expected behavior for a UITableView that's managed by a UITableViewController which **is not** inside a UINavigationController.